# 80GB Intel SSD only allocates 54,49 GB

Tags: ssd

I have two same SSDs (Intel 80GB SSDSA2M080G2GC) and one of the drives now, only has 54,49GB storage capacity where the other still has the normal 74,53GB. The values are from the Management Console.

[image]

On boot at the controller screen shows the same. I tried a firmwareupdate, that changed nothing. Smartvalues say 100% Health.

Any Ideas?

edit: beside that, the SSD works without problems or file losses.

Comment: does one have the system reserved partition on it?

Comment: How new are these devices the total storage of a SSD wil decrease over time

Comment: I presume you have done the obvious, like reformatting, looking for hidden partitions/files, etc. Are you using the same interface slot for both discs? If not, try reformatting after swapping interfaces, and try a different file system temporarily.

Comment: The Bigger one has an system reserved partition, but thats legit. But Pictures Say more then words --> http://www.bumbumtschak.com/img/share/SSDs.PNG

@Ramhound: The one with the Size problem is actually newer. lifetime writes: 12,29TB bs 2,09 TB
Powerontime: 662 days vs 142 days

But is that actually true, that SSDs lose space over time? I thought, they have spare space to relocate.

@ AFH Reformatting etc. doesnt help. The controller detects the wrong size of the ssd.

Comment: The controller is detecting the correct size.

Comment: are there any tools, where i can read out actual data? I'm confused that it still works, with 20gb less storage.

Comment: have you enabled this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_configuration_overlay, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_Protected_Area

Answer (score 1):

Magicandre1981 is right! My SSD had an HPA. Not sure where it came from, but Teskdisk confirmed it and HDAT2 was able to delete it!

Comment: [Host protected area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_protected_area)'s can be used to decrease the shown storage space of an SSD. This gives the SSD more free space to play with, booting performance. Given that: Did you use some 'tuning options' on that drive?

Comment: nice to hear that you fixed it :)

Comment: @Hennes I used that SSD in an older Dell laptop and cloned that HD onto this SSD. I think, that this Dell HDD had an HPA and it was cloned onto the SSD. Don't know if this is possible, but thats the only way I can think of.